# Constructor dependencies injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor

I'm creating a new service via an interface and I'm not skilled enough to get this right. While implementing the code I've got an issue I can't overcome: `_infoSAP` is getting `null` value because it is not instiantiated correctly and I can't find how to do it properly. See code below, issue occurs at `CreateCustomerSAP` line.

```
// all 'using' needed
namespace OurBrand.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : RootController
    {   
        private readonly IModuleSAP _infoSAP;

        //CodeLens: 0 references
        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        //CodeLens: 1 references    
        public AccountController(IModuleSAP customerSAP)
        {
            _infoSAP = customerSAP;
        }

        //CodeLens: 0 references
        public AccountController(IUserData userData, IMapper mapper, ICheckCompanyNumber checkCompanyNumber)
        {
            _userData = userData;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _checkCompanyNumber = checkCompanyNumber;
        }

        public JsonResult APITest(string testValue)
        {    
            var newCustomerSAP = new CustomerSAP_DTO()
            {
                //Properties
            };

            // Here the error occurs: "_infoSAP" is null
            _infoSAP.CreateCustomerSAP(customerDataSAP);

            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace OurBrand.External.Services.Interfaces
{
    public interface IModuleSAP
    {
        void CreateCustomerSAP(CustomerSAP_DTO customerData);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
// all 'using' needed
namespace OurBrand.External.Services
{
    public class ModuleSAP : IModuleSAP
    {
        public void CreateCustomerSAP(CustomerSAP_DTO customerData)
        {
            // Code here

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is with whatever is being used to construct `AccountController`.  Can you show more code relevant to how instances of that class are created?  With what you show as of now, it's hard to guess at the root cause, other than the wrong constructor is being used (either parameterless, or the one that does not take an instance of `IModuleSAP`).

Comment: I've made some tests after your message and found some aspects I didn't notice before: while the parameterless seems to be not needed (I removed it and it worked), if I add ```IModuleSAP``` to the constructor already with instances then the parameterless is again needed (it breaks the code somewhere else). Then I saw Steve Py message and things are starting to make sense to me. I will have another look tomorrow where this controller is being called first.

Comment: I completely agree with @StevePy's answer. Also read this blog post on [the matter](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/), which is a more-eleborate discussion on what Steve basically explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that my issue was at `RegisterTypes`, the newly created `IModuleSAP` was not there. After its creation, things became operative again.

While it was important to notice Steve Py message, only with a support of another DEV that I could find the missing point stated above.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you have 3 constructors with completely different arguments is a big red flag. the point of a constructor is to ensure that an object is initialized with *everything* it will need to execute the methods and such it exposes. Constructors that expose different properties for different scenarios should be avoided because there is no guarantee, especially with dependency injection containers that the correct constructor would have been used for the instance for the method you are calling.

Codelens results are useless for constructor usage with IoC containers because there is no code to inspect for where the constructor would be called. The container will use reflection to discover and instantiate a class instance so they should all report 0 usages. The fact that you have 1 usage for a constructor means you have code that is breaking DI and new-ing up a reference of that class somewhere.

So your class should ideally have one constructor:

```
    public AccountController(IUserData userData, IMapper mapper, ICheckCompanyNumber checkCompanyNumber, IModuleSAP customerSAP)
    {
        _userData = userData;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _checkCompanyNumber = checkCompanyNumber;
        _infoSAP = customerSAP;
    }
```

The issue you are likely encountering is that the instance of the account controller being resolved by the container was actually picking the other constructor leaving your _infoSAP reference uninitialized.

Comment: Humm I agree. I've made some tests (after the initial comment by Sean Skelly) and started to see something in this line you mentioned (but not clearly as you stated). I will look this again tomorrow (now is 9pm).

Comment: To be safe, I'd add null checks to the constructor to guarantee that none of the dependencies can accidentally be null.